# How to trigger a def only once and then stopped being able to call again for a amount of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this code here that take sound from convert to text to make a virtual assistant. But it return the same detected text a few time in a few second. Which trigger an def I have a few time, which I only want to trigger once.
This is the code:

```
            while True:
            data = q.get()
            if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
                dicts = rec.Result()
                
            else:
                dicts = rec.PartialResult()

                print(dicts)
                
                main(dicts)

            if dump_fn is not None:
                dump_fn.write(data)
```

This is the def:

```
def main(dicts):
new_dicts = ast.literal_eval(dicts)
text = new_dicts.get("partial")
if "what" in text:
    if "time" in text:
            time_get("time")
    elif "day" in text:
            time_get("day")
```

Example of output:

```
{
 "partial" : "what time"
}
Time: 13:07:58 pm
{
"partial" : "what time"
}
Time: 13:08:04 pm
{
"partial" : "what time is it"
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is your 'while' loop that starts running over and over.
I'd suggest you removing it or adding exit condition:
`if ...:`
  `break`

Answer (score 0):

I am having difficulties completely grasping your question. As English might not be your first language (as it isn't mine by the way) you might get more precise replies by google translating your question from your native language.
Anyway with that out of the way I believe what you're looking for is the **time module**. You could imp

```
import time


import time

last_time = time.time()

while True:
        dt = time.time() - last_time # dt stands for delta time which stands for time passed.
        
        if dt < 5: #This says as long is dt is smaller than 5 (seconds) just continue the loop and do nothing.
                continue
        else:
                #PASTE YOUR CODE HERE
                last_time = time.time()#this sets the last_time value to the current time.
```

I hope this helps! I hope you're having a blast coding!

Comment: Thank you a lot. I wanted to use google translate but I don't even know how to describe this problem in my language either.

Comment: Yeah I know the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no problem.this how vosk library work. you have partially results, Result and FinalResult variables. vosk is trying to predict each word until you finish talking than try to build complete sentence for you check following code and see how you get final result than keep listening your voice.

code is taking rec.Result() , converting from json to dict, getting text element from it and checking against wake word whis is "oscar" here.

```
import json
import os
import time
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer

if not os.path.exists("model"):
    print(
        "Please download the model from https://github.com/alphacep/kaldi-android-demo/releases and unpack as 'model-en' in the current folder.")
    exit(1)

import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=8000)
stream.start_stream()

model = Model("model")
rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)
stop_recognize = False
while stop_recognize is not True:
    record = stream.read(2000, exception_on_overflow=False)
    if len(record) > 0:
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(record):
            # print(rec.Result())
            prediction = json.loads(rec.Result())
            if prediction['text'] == "oscar":
                print("wake word found")
            #     run your commands here
            else:
                print ("No wake word found",prediction)


print(prediction)
```